# Is there any way to find the pids of children of a program?

Tags: bash

Is there any way to find the pid of children of a program ?

For example I'm starting `pppoe` connection using system program:

```
pon dsl-provider
```

The program will exit after establishing connection and will spawn a `pppd` needed for connection:

```
ps wx | grep pppd
  882 ?        S      0:01 /usr/sbin/pppd call dsl-provider
```

The thing is (I was doing that until now) that I don't want to grep in ps listing, I want an exact answer, and I need this in many circumstances (the above is only an example). How can I do that?

Comment: One hopefully useful hint, that you can use in conjunction with both below answers: If you are ready do background the original process `pon dsl-provider &` you can get its PID with `$!`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pstree` with the `-p` option to show the process tree of a process and its children with pids appended:

```
$ pstree -p `pgrep pppd`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
# somehow get the PID of the parent (882 in your case)
PID=`ps wx | grep pppd | awk '{ print $1; }'`

# formatted output (includes the parent)
ps ax --format pid,ppid,command | grep $PID | grep -v grep
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `ps --ppid ORIGINAL_PROGRAMS_PID` although it might not work if the original program exited.